# DataBind throws ThreadingAbort exception

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm using `DataBind()` on an ASP.NET `GridView`, and it throws a `ThreadingAbort` exception, but only when the `GridView` is currently bound to an empty (but not null) `DataTable` and I call `DataBind()` after linking it to another empty (but not null) `DataTable`.

```
DataTable dt = ... // obtain DataTable with 0 rows
MyGridView.DataSource = dt;
MyGridView.DataBind(); // errors on second time around
```

Any ideas why this should happen, and how to stop it? Thanks

Comment: bind it inside `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: I don't think it is anything to do with IsPostBack - that is true for both attempts to .Bind(), but only the second attempt fails.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
It was throwing an exception in the `_OnDataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)` event handler.